# Convering If-else shell to Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to convert this command to Ansible script. But I am not getting any luck. When module will not help.

```sh
if [ ${EnvType} == "PRE" ]
then
 EnvPrefix="RP"
else 
 EnvPrefix=$(echo "${EnvType}" | cut -c1,3)
fi
export EnvPrefix
```

Essentially i need to export envprefix based on envtype. I can run shell command to findout if envtype is pre but I am receiving blank when i try to export  using shell module.

```yaml
- name: Set Envprefix for other environment
shell: |
  EnvPrefix=$(echo "${EnvType}" | cut -c1,3)
  export EnvPrefix
when: output.stdout != "PRE"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the equivalent

```yaml
- set_fact:
    EnvPrefix: "{{ (EnvType == 'PRE')|
                   ternary('ST',[EnvType.0,EnvType.2]|join) }}"
- command: "export {{ EnvPrefix }}"
```

In case the list of the selections is longer, *map/extract* might be more efficient

```yaml
- set_fact:
    EnvPrefix: "{{ (EnvType == 'PRE')|
                   ternary('ST',[0,2]|map('extract',EnvType)|list|join) }}"
```

Comment: not sure how to cater this in my existing code above. Also i have to export EnvPrefix as well

Comment: Good to know. I've updated both the question and the answer. Is this what you are looking for?